# Calling a contract method on a specific block number using Go

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-invocation

Using the `go-ethereum` library, I'm able to call contract methods using the generated Go bindings:

```
balance, err := wallet.Balance(&bind.CallOpts{
    Pending: false,
    From:    sender,
    Context: ctx,
})
```

However, I'd like to make the above method call for a specific block number.

To do this I would need to do two things:

1. Get the latest block number.

There doesn't seem to be a function to do this dirrectly with the Ethereum client https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient.

In web3.js there's a `getBlockNumber()` method, but I couldn't find the equivalent in Go.

2. Use the obtained block number to call the `balance` method on the smart contract.

The `bind.CallOpts` object doesn't allow you to specify the block number directly.

How would I go about achieving this using the `go-ethereum` library?

Answer (score 2):

1. Get the latest block number:

   ```
   blockHeader, err := ethClient.HeaderByNumber(context.Background(), nil)
   if err != nil {
       return err
   }

   log.Printf("Last block: %s", blockHeader.Number)
   ```
2. Use the obtained block number to call the `balance` method on the smart contract:

   ```
   // import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/hexutil"
   data, err := hexutil.Decode("0xb69ef8a8") // First 4 bytes of keccak256("balance()")
   if err != nil {
       return err
   }
   callMsg := ethereum.CallMsg{
       To:   contractAddress,
       Data: data,
   }
   response := ethClient.CallContract(context.Background(), callMsg, blockHeader.Number)
   ```

   You can specify any block number as `*big.Int` instead of `blockHeader.Number`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `go-ethereum` version 1.8.20 you can make calls to contracts at a specific block number by specifying the `BlockNumber` field in the `CallOpts{}` object.

https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind#CallOpts